# Show that $f_a(z)=z+a-e^z$ has only 1 zero in $Re(z)<0$ and this zero is $<0$. $(a>1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, rouches-theorem

I am trying to use Rouche's Theorem somehow but I can't seem to be able to find a proper function to compare $f_a(z)$ with.

I tried $g(z)=z+a$ but then I can't deal with the $e^z$ term.

Any suggestions or solutions?

Edit:

Suppose $f(z)$ has a root in $Re(z)<0$. This implies that $|z+a|\leq |e^z|=|e^{Re(z)}|<1$. Hence, z has to lie in open ball around $-a$

For $z$ on the unit circle around $-a$

$|g(z)-f(z)|=|e^z|=e^{Re(z)}<1=|g(z)|$

By Rouche's this implies $f(z)$ has 1 zero.

Is this correct? But how does one show that the root is real.

Comment: Hint: $z = x+iy$

Comment: You have to prove that there is only one zero in the entire region $\Re z <0$. You have only considered  a small part of this half-plane so your proof is not correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How bout now?

Comment: @JhonDoe The first part is now correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only shown that $f$ has exactly one zero in the disk with center $-a$ and
radius one. Instead of that disk consider arbitrary rectangles
$$
 R= R(x_1, x_2, y) = \{ z \mid x_1 < \operatorname{Re}(z) < x_2 , -y < \operatorname{Im}(z) < y \}
$$
where $x_1 < -a - 1$,$ -a + 1 < x_2 < 0$ and $y > 1$.
Then your estimate holds on the boundary of $R$:
$$
 |f(z) - (z+a)| = |e^z| = e^{\operatorname{Re}(z)} < 1 < |z + a|
$$
so that $f$ and $(z+a)$ have the same number of zeros (i.e.: *one*) in $R$.
Since the rectangles $R$ exhaust the left half-plane, it follows that
$f$ has exactly one zero on the left half-plane.

Finally, a simple analysis of $f$ restricted to *real* arguments
shows that $f(x) = 0$ for some negative $x \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: With the edit, does my prove work now?

Comment: Yes, that’s fine now.

Comment: @MartinR how did you show that the root is real?